# How to list every public workspace with Yarn 2+?

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, yarnpkg-v2

I'm trying to recreate `lerna`'s [`list` functionality](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/main/commands/list) with Yarn 2, I need to get a list of every public package's name in the workspace. [`yarn workspaces list`](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/workspaces/list) can list all the packages on the workplace, but it returns every package, private included.

Also I need the result in a parseable format, e.g. JSON, or just a plain output with some line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn out its quite tricky, but doable:

```
yarn constraints query "workspace(Cwd), \+ workspace_field(Cwd, 'private', true), workspace_ident(Cwd, Ident)" --json
```

This will give you an NDJSON stream like this:

```
{"Cwd":"packages/yarnpkg-sdks","Ident":"@yarnpkg/sdks"}
{"Cwd":"packages/yarnpkg-shell","Ident":"@yarnpkg/shell"}
```